# Creating a dictionary from a string in dictionary format

Tags: python, json, pandas, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

url="https://www.carinsurance.com/ajax/updatemarkerinfo.json?zc=33013&age=40&gender=Male&coverage_set=full%20-%20100/300/100"
url_get = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_get.content, 'lxml')
test=soup.text
test=test[test.find("zip_code"):]
test2='{'+'"'+test[test.find("zip_code"):]
d=json.loads(test)
e=json.loads(test2)
```

I pulled data from the above URL and I am trying to create a DataFrame with the dictionary values in test2.

The problem I am encountering is I want the zip_code state_abbv to be column indexes as opposed to rows which is the output of d.

I did solve this by re-indexing however, since I am going to loop through multiple zipcodes and append the data on one dataframe I'm looking for something more efficient.

Comment: It's better to add a example of the expected output. Hower, if you already have the zip_code and state_abbv code as row indexes of the dataframe, you can call dataframe.T to get the transpose, and thus what you need

Comment: The expected output would be the transpose, however I wanted a way to do it without having to transpose each df before appending it.

Comment: Put everything in a list an transpose once. Otherwise, seeing an example of the output can always help people to provide better answers.